How to send OSC bundle using python-osc?
On the repository page of python-osc I read:
Building bundles
from pythonosc import osc_bundle_builder
from pythonosc import osc_message_builder

bundle = osc_bundle_builder.OscBundleBuilder(
    osc_bundle_builder.IMMEDIATELY)
msg = osc_message_builder.OscMessageBuilder(address="/SYNC")
msg.add_arg(4.0)
# Add 4 messages in the bundle, each with more arguments.
bundle.add_content(msg.build())
msg.add_arg(2)
bundle.add_content(msg.build())
msg.add_arg("value")
bundle.add_content(msg.build())
msg.add_arg(b"\x01\x02\x03")
bundle.add_content(msg.build())

sub_bundle = bundle.build()
# Now add the same bundle inside itself.
bundle.add_content(sub_bundle)
# The bundle has 5 elements in total now.

bundle = bundle.build()
# You can now send it via a client as described in other examples.

But it's not clear to me how to "send it via a client as described in other examples".
I tried:
client.send_message(bundle)

but it returns:

SimpleUDPClient.send_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'

and
client.send_message("/test", bundle)

returns:

Infered arg_value type is not supported

What is the correct syntax to send OSC bundles?
Here how the client is constructed, from the example in the same page:
import argparse
import random
import time

from pythonosc import udp_client


if __name__ == "__main__":
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument("--ip", default="127.0.0.1",
      help="The ip of the OSC server")
  parser.add_argument("--port", type=int, default=5005,
      help="The port the OSC server is listening on")
  args = parser.parse_args()

  client = udp_client.SimpleUDPClient(args.ip, args.port)

  for x in range(10):
    client.send_message("/filter", random.random())
    time.sleep(1)


You're not showing how you construct client. Given the error message, I'd wager you haven't constructed a client, but you have client = SimpleUDPClient somewhere.

@AKX I'm going to update the question but the code is provided in the same page

Looking at the source code I found the solution:
client.send(bundle)

but this is not specified in the example.
By the way also the bundle example is wrong because it adds multiple times the same content. The correct way to send a bundle is:
bundle = osc_bundle_builder.OscBundleBuilder(osc_bundle_builder.IMMEDIATELY)
msg = osc_message_builder.OscMessageBuilder(address="/foo/bar/1")
msg.add_arg(1)
msg.add_arg(2)
# add other arguments as needed

bundle.add_content(msg.build())
bundle = bundle.build()
client.send(bundle)


Nice! I made a PR to add this to the example. https://github.com/attwad/python-osc/pull/179
